# ASP NET CORE MVC - CLI Command like PHP Symfony

Tags: c#, php, symfony, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a question. Does ASP NET CORE support creating custom CLI commands? Like for example `Command` class from PHP Symfony.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

In Symfony you first create your own class that inherits from `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command` and then you can call created command like this:

`php bin/console TestCommand`

This is super useful for many cases - for example, business needs quick scripting.

Does ASP NET CORE MVC support this or not?

Comment: Yes. Look up `dotnet tool` but it's a dotnet core thing, not  ASP.Net

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create). It is not specific to asp.net, it is a dotnet cli thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For command line tools that are more or less universal and possibly try to adapt to the project they are called for, dotnet tools are okay, however they don't seem to be well suited to the case of actual project specific commands that have access to the project classes, because you have to pack them as nugets and so on, it could be made easier for this case.

For special project specific commands it may be easier to just parse and recognize special command line arguments in the webapp's Main method, and then you can do anything you want including accessing DI services from the host etc. It is certainly easier to manage than nuget packing and then tool installing a tool that itself depends on the project to function correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking exactly for this option!